Hourglass and suspending when communicating FireDac with SQL Server 2012
I'm converting ADO Connections and AdoQuerys to FDConnection and FDQuerys in my Delphi project to improve connection quality to the SQL Server 2012 database.
The previous Ado version worked fine for running query commands, but in the current FD version, the system hangs most of the time.
Cursor shows hourglass icon and SQL word below hourglass cursor and the program is suspended, so that the user is forced to use َAlt+Ctrl+Del keys. Maybe FireDac is not compatible with SQL Server 2012?
I tried different modes of CMDExecMode<ResourceOption on FDQuerys but long response of queries did not get solved as the system was suspended
